# Number of Generators of the Cohomology Ring of the Grassmannians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, discrete-geometry, grassmannians, flag-varieties, schubert-calculus

For complex projective space, its cohomology ring has $1$ generator. Extending up to the first Grassmannian which is not a projective space, that is, Grass$(4,2)$, a direct investigation shows that it has $2$ generators, and this number is minimal. Moreover, for Grass$(5,2)$ I seem to get $2$ generators, and for Grass$(6,3)$ I think I can show that it has $3$ generators. Hence I am tempted to conjecture that the cohomology ring of the Grassmannian Grass$(n,r)$ has a minimal set of $r$ generators. Is this true, and if so, who is it proved in an easy way.

Comment: For r<=2n, the chern classes of the tautological bundle are a minimal generating set. That the set is minimal follows from the formula for the graded dimension of the cohomology ring

Comment: Sorry, but " For $r<=2n$" doesn't make sense to me. Do you mean $r \leq \frac{1}{2}n$?

Comment: Have a look at this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian#Cohomology_ring_of_the_complex_Grassmannian).